# xerces-c++ compile/linking question

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, static-libraries, linker-errors

After installing Xerces-C++ (XML library):

```
./configure --disable-shared
./make
./make-install
ldconfig
```

And writing the simple program (xmlval.cpp):

```
#include <stdio>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOM.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "HI" << std::endl;
}
```

And compiling:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include -o xmlval xmlval.cpp /usr/local/lib/libxerces-c.a
```

The compile result is a bunch of lines like:

```
/usr/local/lib/libxerces-c.a(CurlNetAccessor.o): In function `xercesc_3_0::CurlNetAccessor::cleanupCurl()':
/home/stullbd/xerces-c-3.0.1/src/xercesc/util/NetAccessors/Curl/CurlNetAccessor.cpp:78: undefined reference to `curl_global_cleanup'
/usr/local/lib/libxerces-c.a(CurlNetAccessor.o): In function `xercesc_3_0::CurlNetAccessor::initCurl()':
/home/stullbd/xerces-c-3.0.1/src/xercesc/util/NetAccessors/Curl/CurlNetAccessor.cpp:70: undefined reference to `curl_global_init'
/usr/local/lib/libxerces-c.a(CurlURLInputStream.o): In function `~CurlURLInputStream':
/home/stullbd/xerces-c-3.0.1/src/xercesc/util/NetAccessors/Curl/CurlURLInputStream.cpp:168: undefined reference to `curl_multi_remove_handle'
```

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to miss linking with curl, try adding `-lcurl`.